# Why does this query take so long, and how I can increase its performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, query-optimization, database-performance

I have a query which, to summarize, inserts `N` identical rows into a table with the only difference being that 1 column's values go from `0`, `1`, ..., `N` and I don't inserted insert any if there is already a column with that value. My procedure is

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i INT = 0;
    WHILE(@i <= @boardPageCeiling)
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM PageArchives WHERE PageType = 'Board' AND PageNum = @i)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO PageArchives
                (PageType, ThreadId, Html, PageNum, RetrievalAttempted, RetrievalSucceeded, RetrievalDate, RetrievalPriority, ProcessAttempted, ProcessingSucceeded, ProcessDate)
            VALUES
                ('Board', NULL, NULL, @i, 0, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL)
        END
        SET @i = @i + 1;
    END
END
```

and this is taking 20+ seconds to execute when `boardPageCeiling` = `6000`. Seems extraordinarily long given the complexity.

Comment: Please check your query using Query analyzer and also use debug points.

Comment: What is the datatype of the variable `@boardPageCeiling`. Please use the Query Analyzer.

Comment: possible to change this to actually be set-based insertion rather than iterating? Trivial to create a set of the necessary data to insert and actually do that in the form of a INSERT INTO SELECT. As of now, it is doing at a minimum 6K queries with that exists function.  Others have mentioned indexes, analyzers, etc and that'd help with this but believe you'd see better results with overhauling the query

Comment: Do you have indexes on PageType and PageNum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert the below table:

```
WITH NumberTable  AS (
  SELECT 1 as Number
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Number+1
  FROM NumberTable  
  WHERE Number < 100 
)
SELECT 'Board', NULL, NULL, Number, 0, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL FROM NumberTable  
where Number not in (SELECT PageNum FROM PageArchives WHERE PageType = 'Board')
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Just a sample query,replace "100" by your self"

Comment: Maximum recursion gets exceeded

Comment: add query at last ..  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

Comment: It can make recursion level more than 100

Comment: Any question else?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a single query.  The only remotely tricky part is generating a sequence of numbers:

```
WITH digits(d) as (
      SELECT *
      FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) v(d)
     ),
     n(n) as (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 as seqnum
      FROM d CROSS JOIN d CROSS JOIN d CROSS JOIN d
     )
INSERT INTO PageArchives (PageType, PageNum, RetrievalDate, RetrievalPriority, ProcessAttempted)
    SELECT 'Board', PageNum, 0, 0, 0
    FROM n
    WHERE n.n <= @boardPageCeiling AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PageArchives pa WHERE pa.PageNum = n.n);
```

I removed the `NULL` values from the `INSERT` because these are probably set to `NULL` by default.

Comment: @user7127000 . . . Fixed the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve that  query by using a merge statement

Comment: It might combine the WHERE NOT EXISTS() with the INSERT, but it will still run slow as long as the approach is line by line (tip: google for "SQL RBAR")